# How do I log onto my mojang account on minecraft Pe?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I want to connect to servers and what not but it isn't working, do I need to log onto mojang first and if so how do I do it on the app?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to log into your Mojang account to access multiplayer in Minecraft: Pocket Edition. Your Google/Microsoft account is all you need in order to access multiplayer with friends through Realms or localised servers on your friends' device. You can also use the IP address and the port for private servers. But to answer the question posed, you do not need to log into a Mojang account to access multiplayer.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to a server by:-
1. Open Minecraft PE.
2. Click on play button and and press new button at the top right corner.
3. Then click on the button beside advanced at the top right corner which looks like this- *+->*
4. Now add Name, IP/Address and Port andearthquake click to the add server option.
5. Now you can connect to the server.

Comment: I don't think this actually addresses what the question was asking.